# Webapi validation errors returned to client ("problem details" RFC7807) and advice on best practices to process client side

Tags: validation, error-handling, webapi

So, I've created a WebAPI with some validation on some properties - I submit a request which triggers a fail in the vailidation and I get the following (expected) response:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-9da39033dee509aca32deda2acd9d0bb-4ed4d70435a41383-00",
    "errors": {
        "LastName": [
            "The Last Name field is required."
        ],
        "FirstName": [
            "The First Name field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

I understand this is to do with "problem details" (RFC7807) and can find many articles about generating these errors server side, but what I'm wondering is what is the 'normal' way of consuming these client side (no front end frameworks, just jquery).

I can write something manually to deal with this but that doesnt feel right, I feel I'm missing something. Can someone give me a nudge in the right direction/guidance.